# Installing Ubuntu Server from USB installs to wrong location?

Tags: 12.04, server

I'm trying to install Ubuntu Server 12.04 from a USB and I've gotten my iso file and created the installer on the USB using Universal USB Installer. I then start my laptop, booting from the USB and the installer runs but in the end it seems to install to the flash drive. During the installation I select my normal hard drive as the location to write to but it won't boot without the flash drive still in. Any ideas?

Edit: I believe my problem might be coming from an instruction during the install that asks if GRUB should be installed to the master boot record, and refers to it as "install the GRUB boot loader to the master boot record of your FIRST hard drive" right now in my BIOS, the flash drive is listed as the first hard drive which is the only way I could get it to boot into the install. I could try installing by CD.

Comment: please check that if you are selected a correct HDD ext4 partition for installing ubuntu server.

Comment: should be okay, I do select the right location and choose to partition the entire disk without LVM

Comment: are  select the partitioned ext4 filesystem to install ubuntu server?

Comment: did you installed ubuntu server on HDD?If yes,then the screen displays what when you boot from hard-disk?

Comment: I believe I made the right choices through the setup. If I boot without the flash drive in, I get a black screen with blinking cursor. Booting with it still in I get the normal server startup with login and command line.

Answer (score 1):

Solved. Everything was installing to the selected hard drive except for the Grub boot loader. During the installation process it can only install it to the system's first hard drive and if you have a wonky situation where you need to switch the USB to be the first drive in order to get the installation process going then you're in trouble in the case of Ubuntu Server. I tried command line to install Grub to the system with no luck and eventually created an install CD and that solved the problem.